# Why is $(x^{2n+1} - (2n+1)x^{n+1} + (2n+1)x^n - 1)/(x-1)^3$ irreducible?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Consider the following polynomial

$$
f_n(x)=x^{2n+1} - (2n+1)x^{n+1} + (2n+1)x^n - 1
$$

Try the first $n$, I find that the $(x-1)^3$ is its factor:

$$
f_1(x)=(x-1)^3,\\
f_2(x)=(x-1)^3 (x^2+3x+1),\\
f_3(x)=(x-1)^3 (x^4+3x^3+6x^2+3x+1),\\
\cdots
$$
and that this is the complete factorization of $f_n(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

But how can you prove that factoring out $(x-1)^3$ gives the complete factorization over $\mathbb{Z}$? That is, how can you prove that $f_n(x)/(x-1)^3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$?

PS: I use Mathematica to test $n\leqslant 1000$, all is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "only"?  That $(x-1)^3$ is a factor but $(x-1)^4$ is not?

Comment: @EricWofsey I mean that the remaining part, i.e. $f_n(t)/(x-1)^3$ is irreducible.

Comment: I guess by irreducible you mean irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Actually I mean for irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. Sorry for that.

Comment: Well, it is equivalent for monic polynomials with integer coefficients.

Comment: It is easy enough to verify that $f_n(x)/(x-1)^3$ always has the same pattern of triangular number coefficients rising and then falling as in your examples, by just doing the long division. Not sure how to show this polynomial is irreducible, though...

Comment: Yeah, the pattern is easy to find, but the problem is how to prove...

Comment: Are you sure that the task is to prove that $\frac{f_n(x)}{(x-1)^3}$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, or just that any other factor $x-x_0$ with $x_0 \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{1\}$ must have multiplicity $\leq 3$? What does "largest factor" mean to you?

Comment: @Christoph I mean it's irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It is easy to see that $f_n$ doesn't have any linear factors rather than $x-1$, however this is not enough to show that $f_n(x)/(x-1)^3$ is irreducible...

Comment: The pattern of coefficients means that if $x=a$ is a root then so is $x=\frac 1a$ in case the symmetry helps.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a proof in the special case that $2n+1$ is prime (and $n>1$).

Let $g_n(x)=f_n(x)/(x-1)^3$ and let $h_n(x)=g_n(x+1)$.  By dividing $f_n(x)$ by $x-1$ three times using long division, we find $$g_n(x)=\binom{2}{2}x^{2n-2}+\binom{3}{2}x^{2n-3}+\dots+\binom{n}{2}x^n+\binom{n+1}{2}x^{n-1}+\binom{n}{2}x^{n-2}+\dots+\binom{3}{2}x+\binom{2}{2}.$$   Now note that $$f_n(x)-(x-1)^{2n+1}=x^{2n+1} - 1 - (x-1)^{2n+1} + (2n+1)(x^n-x^{n+1})$$ is divisible by $2n+1$ since every term of $x^{2n+1}-1-(x-1)^{2n+1}$ is divisible by $2n+1$ (the coefficients have the form $\pm\binom{2n+1}{k}$ for $0<k<2n+1$ which is divisible by $2n+1$ since it is prime).  It follows that $h_n(x)-x^{2n-2}$ is also divisible by $2n+1$.  That is, every term except the leading term of $h_n(x)$ is divisible by $2n+1$.  Moreover, the constant term of $h_n(x)$ is 
\begin{align*}
g_n(1) &= \binom{2}{2}+\binom{3}{2}+\dots+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n+1}{2}+\binom{n}{2}+\dots+\binom{3}{2}+\binom{2}{2} \\
&=\binom{n+2}{3}+\binom{n+1}{3} \\
&=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.
\end{align*}
(Alternatively, $g_n(1)$ can be computed as $f_n'''(1)/6$.) In particular, the constant term of $h_n(x)$ is not divisible by $(2n+1)^2$.  So, by Eisenstein's criterion for the prime $2n+1$, $h_n(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, and hence so is $g_n(x)=h_n(x-1)$.

(This approach sometimes also works when $2n+1$ is not prime; for instance, $h_4(x)$ turns out to still satisfy Eisenstein's criterion for the prime $3$.  However, $h_7(x)$ does not satisfy Eisenstein's criterion for any prime.)

Answer (score 2):

You can show that $\forall i\in\{0,1,2\}:f_n^{(i)}(1)=0$ and that $f_n^{(3)}(1)\neq 0$.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Read the comments on the OP.

Answer (score 2):

$(x-1)^n$ is a factor of the polynomial $f(x)$ with real coefficients iff
$f(1)=f'(1)=f''(1)=\cdots=f^{(n-1)}(1)=0$.
Here
$$f(1)=1-(2n+1)+(2n+1)-1=0,$$
$$f'(1)=(2n+1)-(n+1)(2n+1)+n(2n+1)=0,$$
$$f''(1)=(2n+1)2n-(n+1)n(2n+1)+n(n-1)(2n+1)=0$$
and
$$f'''(1)=(2n+1)2n(2n-1)-(n+1)n(n-1)(2n+1)+n(n-1)(n-2)(2n+1)
=(2n+1)n(n+1)>0.$$

Comment: But you only consider the $(x-1)^n$. How about other things, e.g. $(2x-1)^2$?